# How to service Toyota Ractis 2007 model CVT gear box

Tags: toyota

I have a toyota Ractis 2007 model almost clocking 200,000 miles but am nervous as hell to service the gear box. She still shifts gorgeously like a baby. I noticed though the gear box seals are starting to wear out coz i noticed a bit of sweating of the ATF at the junction of the gearbox and the drive shafts. Bottom line it's a time bomb anyway as much as My mechanic estimated a couple of tens of thousands miles before the seals completely fail. If someone knows a how to service this particular gearbox i would highly appreciate. NOT HOW TO CHANGE THE SEALS BUT JUST THE NORMAL SERVICE OF CHANGING THE ATF.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!